# "to rub smth into a surface" vs "to rub a surface with smth"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

I found 2 sentences:

> 1. We rubbed some polish into the surface of the wood.
> 2. First rub the baking tray well with butter.

Can I rephrase them as "we rubbed the surface of the wood with some polish" and "first rub butter into the baking tray well"?

Comment: I don't think we rub polish _into_ the surface, rather **on** the surface.

Comment: You can rub polish ***into*** wood, because we can imagine that some small fraction of the polish is actually ***absorbed*** into the wood (like rubbing ointment into your skin). But it makes little sense to talk of rubbing butter into a baking tray, since a metal tray is incapable of absorbing butter.

Comment: IMO the verb **rub** is incorrect for applying butter to a baking tray. **Smear** or **coat** will do, because the job is no better if you spend some time rubbing the tray with butter, and anyway you just tip the tray so that molten butter runs across it.